# Globally handle jQuery's AJAX timeouts without aborting

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I know about jQuery's `timeout` property you can set on `$.ajaxSetup`, but this aborts the currently timedout request.

What options do I have to monitor the time taken for each separate AJAX request globally for feedback purposes for the user sat waiting.

Pseudo code:

```
if(timeTaken > 1000){
    // taking a long time
} else if (timeTaken > 5000){
    // this is embarrassing, please refresh!
}
```

But implemented globally with jQuery's AJAX...

Answer (score 0):

You have to look ajaxStart() and .ajaxStop() methods.

```
var totalTime = null;
var cachedTime = null;

function alertLoadingTime() {
    if(!totalTime) return;
    var loadingTime = totalTime / 1000;
    console.log("loaded " + loadingTime + " seconds");
}

function timingStart() {
    cachedTime = new Date;
}

function timingEnd() {
    var endTime = new Date;
    totalTime += endTime - cachedTime;
    cachedTime = null;
    alertLoadingTime();
}

$(document).ajaxStart(timingStart);

$(document).ajaxStop(timingEnd);
```

then check totalTime to alert smth.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had something similar but this falls over somewhat when you have multiple, simultaneous requests happening...

Comment: then you may make your ajax calls synchronous for that page   jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: false }); make your calls then make   jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: true}); again